# c# WebRequest to Google API Bad Request

Tags: c#, google-api

When I run this code to call the Google API, all I get is a 'Bad Request' error, but I don't know where I'm going wrong.

The code is being returned no problem from the authorization page on Google, it's when the code gets to the part below that it fails.  Please could someone tell me where I'm going wrong here?

I'm aware that there are libraries for this, but I'm trying to understand how to do this the RESTful way as a learning exercise.

Thanks

```
   var code = Request.QueryString["code"];

    var accessToken = string.Empty;
    var req0 = WebRequest.Create("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token");
    req0.Method = "POST";
string postData = string.Format("code={0}&client_id={1}&client_secret={2}&redirect_uri=        {3}&grant_type=authorization_code",
code, //the code i got back
"xxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
"xxx",
Url.Encode("http://localhost/home/callback")
); //my return URI

byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
req0.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
req0.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
using (Stream dataStream = req0.GetRequestStream())
{
dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
dataStream.Close();
        }
        try
        {
            using (WebResponse response = req0.GetResponse())
            {
                using (var dataStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream))
                    {
                        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        var ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                        accessToken = ser.DeserializeObject(responseFromServer).ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (WebException wex) 
        { 
            Debug.WriteLine(wex.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());

        }
```

Comment: Have you looked at the request on the wire, e.g. with Wireshark?

Comment: Hi John, I looked at it in Fiddler, but it's over https so I'm not sure what I can glean from it?

Comment: Rats, I hadn't spotted the HTTPS-ness. Have you at least checked that `postData` looks reasonable?

Comment: I've even url encoded all the individual variables, and still : Bad Request.  The code above was even lifted from S.O. from a post where it apparently works.  I've even tried this on two different networks to rule out a network specific problem.  I'm pulling my hair out...

Comment: are you sure you need to POST not GET?

Comment: I need to send data, not just retrieve it.

Comment: You could probably try fiddler to build a correct request first and then port to WebRequest. https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer has a sample request which looks identical to yours but you can cross check.

Comment: I am going to take a quick break and beat myself over the head repeatedly with a heavy reference book.  The callback uri had a trailing slash in the original call, but missing in the code above.  It now works.  Thanks to Jon and Sandeep for both telling me to look at what I was sending. This, inadvertently, led me to the missing forward slash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google API is very finicky when it comes to what you have entered into the API Console for your client id return URI, and what you enter in your code to call it.

I was missing the trailing forward slash.  That was all.  Lesson learnt...

Thanks to Jon and Sandeep for help point me in the right direction by comparing what was in the network traffic, and what I should have been sending.